# Get client side's cookies when use dynamic route in next JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working on projects with nextJS and express now.
I'm using express as rest API with middleware that add user on request based on client side's cookie(jwt) and found server cannot read cookies from my frontend pages.
I know backend has no problem, because I'm using very similar logic like below.(You can just skip the code)

private.middleware.ts

```
const authenticate = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Response | void => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    const user = decodeJWT(token);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthorized", err });
  }
};
```

public.middleware.ts

```
const userToReq = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Response | void => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    if (token) {
      const user = decodeJWT(token);
      req.user = user;
    }
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthorized", err });
  }
};
```

So the problem is not on backend and I figured out it's related with my frontend - next js.
I'm using dynamic route and have to get API based on parameter on the page. So I was trying to get it from getStaticProps function below the component. But the problem what I found was they don't use cookies because this page is made on server.
But I found I cannot just do normal static generation because I have to use dynamic route. I need getStaticPaths and getStaticProps.

I just tried to use useEffect in react component but I found it's hard to use parameter in component.

Is there any way I can use client side's cookie when I use dynamic route on nextjs?

Magazines.ts

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const {
    data: { Magazines },
  }: any = await myAxios.get(`/magazines`);
  const paths = Magazines.map((magazine: any) => `/magazines/${magazine.id}`);

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
  const { params } = context;
  console.log(context);
  const res = await myAxios.get(`/magazines/${params.pid}`);
  const {
    data: { Magazines },
  }: any = await res;
  return { props: { Magazines } };
}
```

myAxios.ts

```
... 

const headerConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
};

const myAxios: AxiosInterface = {
  get(path) {
    return axios.get(URL + path, headerConfig);
  },
...
}

...
```